# find and replace regex for reformatting the value

Tags: regex

I have a text like `:value_subvalue` that I want to transform to `:value[:subvalue]`.

I have a find & replace field in Coda where I can enter a regex to find and replace.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Can you post a big piece of text that imitates the text that you want to work on? Otherwise, the regex may not work for you.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm guessing PCRE (or subset of it). From my search Coda is a text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't said what language, so this is a generic answer:

- Search regex: `(:[a-z]+)_([a-z]+)`
- Replacement:  `\1[:\2]`

If you're doing this in java, the group refs would be `$1` and `$2`